# Webgl binding of a Framebuffer and Renderbuffer

Tags: colors, webgl, pixel, framebuffer

I want to get the pixel-color from the framebuffer.
I try to bind a Framebuffer but I get the message "this combination of attachments does not work".

```
RenderingEngine.prototype.getPixel = function(x, y, drawObject){
var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
framebuffer.width = this.canvas.width;
framebuffer.height = this.canvas.height;

var depthBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

// allocate renderbuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);  

// attach renderebuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
   alert("this combination of attachments does not work");
}
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

    drawObject.draw();

var pixel = new Uint8Array(4);
gl.readPixels(x, y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
console.log(pixel);
return pixel;
```

}

---

## update #1

I changed my code like this. But I get allways black Color ([0, 0, 0, 0]). Can you say what is wrong now?

```
RenderingEngine.prototype.getPixel = function(x, y, drawObject){
var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
framebuffer.width = this.canvas.width;
framebuffer.height = this.canvas.height;

var depthBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);


// allocate renderbuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, framebuffer.width, framebuffer.height);  

// attach renderebuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

var colorBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
// allocate colorBuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.RGBA4, framebuffer.width, framebuffer.height);  

// attach colorbuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
   alert("this combination of attachments does not work");
}

renderingEngine.draw(drawObject);

var pixel = new Uint8Array(4);
gl.readPixels(x, y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
console.log(pixel);
return pixel;
```

}

---

## update #2

My error was by drawing. This code works. But there is something strange. The rendered scene is mirrored horizontally. Do you know why?

```
RenderingEngine.prototype.getPixel = function(x, y, drawObject){
var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
framebuffer.width = this.canvas.width;
framebuffer.height = this.canvas.height;

var depthBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);


// allocate renderbuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, framebuffer.width, framebuffer.height);  

// attach renderebuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

var colorBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
// allocate colorBuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.RGBA4, framebuffer.width, framebuffer.height);  

// attach colorbuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
   alert("this combination of attachments does not work");
}

renderingEngine.draw(drawObject);

var pixel = new Uint8Array(4);
gl.readPixels(x, y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
console.log(pixel);
return pixel;
}
```

Comment: You've only attached a depth renderbuffer. You need to attach a color renderbuffer or color texture as well. I don't think you can render only to a depth renderbuffer.

Comment: I changed my code like this:

Comment: I copied your updates up to your question above. Could you please delete your 2 answers below? It's not really appropriate to post updates to your question as answers on SO. Otherwise, as for why it's flipped I assume you mean vertically not horizontally?  Just remember 0,0 in WebGL is the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```js
function log(msg) {
  var pre = document.createElement("pre");
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(pre);
}

var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");

var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

var depthBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

// allocate renderbuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);  

// attach renderebuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

var colorBuffer = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
// allocate colorBuffer
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.RGBA4, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);  

// attach colorbuffer
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
   alert("this combination of attachments does not work");
}

gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.25, 1, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
             
var pixel = new Uint8Array(4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
log(pixel[0] + "," + pixel[1] + "," + pixel[2] + "," + pixel[3]);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>  
</body>
```

Although if it was me I'd attach a texture for the color attachment instead of a render buffer.

Comment: why 136 ? the first color is 0.5, or 255 * 0.5 is not 136

Comment: ahh ok RGBA is float in 4 bits (4 bits in integer = 0..15).  136 = (8/15) * 255 ; 68 = (4/15) * 255 !

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [WebGLFundamentals](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html):
It's important to note WebGL only promises 3 combinations of attachments work. According to [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#FBO_ATTACHMENTS) the only guaranteed combinations of attachments are:

```
COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture
COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture + DEPTH_ATTACHMENT = DEPTH_COMPONENT16 renderbuffer
COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture + DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT = DEPTH_STENCIL renderbuffer
```